# Why an empty is being formed in this case

Tags: jquery

When i click on the ordersconfirm Button .

The output it is being formed is

```
[
    {
        "toppings": [
            {
                "name": "Quantity      1",
                "value": [
                    "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML",
                    "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "crusts": []
    }
]
```

I am not able to find out why the crusts array is being formed empty

This is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/N2ymz/

The code that is used for the crusts array formation is

```
     $(this).closest('.prd-items-detials').next('.Crust-details').find('.tdHeading').each(function () {
        values = [];
        $(this).parent().find('.tpActive').each(function () {
            values.push($(this).text().trim());
        });
        if(values.length>0)
        {
            crusts.push({
                'name': $(this).text().trim(),
                'value': values
            });
        }
    });
```

This is the HTML Part

```
<div id="myordersdiv" style="display: block;">
   <ul>
      <li class="myorderhead active">
         <h5>
            My Orders
            <i class="myorderhead22">1</i>
         </h5>
      </li>
      <div id="ordersdiv">
         <div id="addtoordersdiv4">
            <div class="prd-items-detials">
               <ul>
                  <li class="head">
                     <form>
                        <label item_id_itr_some="label4" class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">Popcorn Plain salted</label>
                     </form>
                  </li>
                  <li class="prd-items-qt">
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
            <div style="display: block;" class="Topping-details" id="4">
               <section id="topping_tsection_4">
                  <aside>
                     <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>

                     <section class="secclass"><a  topping_id="1"  topp_name="Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML" top_price="25" class="tpActive" qt_val="4_ZZ_0_ZZ_0">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML</a>
                     </section>

                     <section class="secclass"><a  topping_id="2"  topp_name="Honey with Carmel  10 ML" top_price="25" class="tpActive" qt_val="4_ZZ_0_ZZ_1">Honey with Carmel  10 ML</a>
                     </section>

                  </aside>
               </section>
            </div>
            <div style="display: block;" class="Crust-details" id="4">
               <section id="crust_tsection_4">
                  <aside>
                     <h6 class="tdHeading">Quantity      1</h6>

                     <section class="crustsecclass"><a  crust_id="7"  crust_name="Honey with Chocolate Sauce  20 ML" crust_cost="25" class="tpActive">Honey with Chocolate Sauce  20 ML</a>
                     </section>

                     <section class="crustsecclass"><a data-id="4" crust_id="8"  crust_name="Honey with Carmel  20 MLRs 30" crust_cost="25" class="tpActive" >Honey with Carmel  20 MLRs 30</a>
                     </section>

                  </aside>
               </section>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </ul>
</div>
<input type="button" id="ordersconfirm" value="Submit Orders">
```

could anybody please help me how to resolve this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with there is no `Crust-details` here -

```
$(this).closest('.prd-items-detials').next('.Crust-details') // line 20
```

because `next()` expects the very next sibling to have that class ("Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, *it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.*"), but it doesn't. You need to use `nextAll()` ("Get all following siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.")

```
$(this).closest('.prd-items-detials').nextAll('.Crust-details')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/N2ymz/4/
http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Answer (score -1):

Found it. . On line 3 you are declaring the crust object.

```
var crusts = [];
```

and based on the conditions on line 34, no value is being pushed in this. The empty object is then being pushed in the final products object on line 43

```
products.push({
           'toppings': toppings,
            'crusts': crusts
        });
```

Use a condition to avoid this :

```
if(crusts.length > 0){
            products.push({
               'toppings': toppings,
                'crusts': crusts
            });
        }
        else
        {
            products.push({
               'toppings': toppings
            });
        }
```

[**Update JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitsnghn/N2ymz/1/)